# How to install SSRS 2008 plugin for VS 2008sp1

Tags: plugins, ssrs-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I want to design a report with new SSRS feature called tablix, but it seems I've previous version of SSRS installed because instead of tablices there are matrices, tables and lists.

Where can I get a newer version of SSRS? (I've already googled all over the web but have found nothing)

**Installed prerequisites:**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) -
  10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86)  Mar 29 2009 10:27:29 Copyright (c) 1988-2008
  Microsoft Corporation Enterprise
  Edition on Windows NT 5.1  
  (Build 2600: Service Pack 3).
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version
  9.0.30729.1 SP Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
- SQL Server Reporting Services 
  Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
  Services Designers  Version
  10.0.2531.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was quite simple: I needed to install new version of ReportViewer.dll. After that everything worked perfectly.